# How can I use face extracted from bounding box in my face recognition code.?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, matlab-cvst

I have three persons in front of camera and using `FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;` I am getting bounding box around all the three faces. I want to track a particular face which is saved in a database of my face recognition code. For this, I am using the code below but getting errors:

```
temp = getdata(vid,1);
index1 = bbox(1,:);
face1 = temp(index1(2):index1(2)+index1(4),index1(1):index1(1)+index1(3),:);

R = imagesc(face1);
name1 = recognize(R);            %.....my face recognition function
```

I am getting error shown below:

```
Error using rgb2gray>parse_inputs (line 81) MAP must be a m x 3 array.

Error in rgb2gray (line 35) X = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in get_face (line 11) img=rgb2gray(img);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: **MAP must be an m x 3 array.**

Comment: @cheema - Basically what Robert Harvey said.  The error that you have posted has nothing to do with the code that you have written here.  The error is happening when you are calling `rgb2gray` on your input image, but that input image is not properly structured according to what `rgb2gray` is expecting.  Can you post the code for `get_face`?

Comment: thanks alot for the answer. here I have code for get_face                function img=get_face(img)

%detect face using vision.CascadeObjectDetector

FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;

% Automatisch mithilfe von Face Detection 
 bb = step(FaceDetect,img);

 img=imcrop(img,bb);
 img=rgb2gray(img);
           
end     and then used in face recognition function as             function name=recognize(img)
img=get_face(img);   
img=imresize(img,[100 100]);
img=double(img(:));

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `rgb2gray` you should check if `img` is indeed an rgb image, i. e. with the size of M-by-N-by-3.